# how to split up a string by delims and then select part of it

Tags: batch-file

current code:

```
set str=11.22.33
for /F "tokens=1* delims=." %%a in ("%str%") do (
  echo %%a
)
```

I wish to produce the following outcome: `.22.33`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
set str=11.22.33
for /F "tokens=2,3 delims=." %%a in ("%str%") do (
echo .%%a.%%b
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Monacraft has a working option.

Here is another option:

```
set "str=11.22.33"
for /f "tokens=2* delims=." %%A in ("%str%") do echo .%%a
```

And yet another option

```
set "str=11.22.33"
echo .%str:*.=%
```